# Validation rule firing on approval process rejection

Tags: validation-rule, approval-process

`Case.Rejection_Reason__c` should get populated before rejecting the case using approval process.

Looks like validation rules are getting fired.

```
AND(
ISPICKVALUE(Case.Status, 'Rejected'),
ISPICKVALUE(Case.Rejecttion_reason__c, '')
)
```

> Error Message : Please choose Rejection reason before rejecting the
> case.

Please suggest how we can achieve this scenario.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Write a before update trigger on Case object to update the approval rejection comments to case rejection field.

Please follow the below reference link and modify as per your need.

https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=9060G000000I3uzQAC

**If it is helps for you, please mark it as best Answer.**

Thank you!!

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.